# Зарегистрированные пользователи могут оставлять комментарии. Не получаеться отправить коментарий в Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

При отправке комментария, коммент должен идти на проверку модератора сайта и только потом появиться на сайте. Я закоментировал часть кода, это для незарегистрированных пользователей и он прекрасно работает(просто считывает поля  имени и комментария на сайте). Столкнулся с проблемой, что не получается отправлять комментарии от зарегистрированных пользователей, кто может помочь?

```
@method_decorator(csrf_protect, name='dispatch')
class DetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'post.html'
    model = Page
    context_object_name = 'post'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['similars'] = self.model.objects.filter(topic=context['post'].topic)[:4]
        context['category'] = self.model.category
        context['comment'] = Comment.objects.filter(
            page=self.object, moderated=True).order_by('-datetime')[:10]
        return context

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.form = CommentForm(self.request.POST)

        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        '''
        if self.form.is_valid():
            self.form.cleaned_data['page'] = self.object
            Comment.objects.create(**self.form.cleaned_data)
            messages.add_message(
                self.request, messages.INFO,
                'Thanks! Your review is on moderation.'
            )'''
        if self.form.is_valid():

            comment = Comment()
            comment.page = self.object
            comment.author = auth.get_user(request)
            comment.comment = self.form.cleaned_data['comment']
            comment.save()
            messages.add_message(
                self.request, messages.INFO,
                'Thanks! Your review is on moderation.'
            )
        else:
            context['form'] = self.form
            messages.add_message(
                self.request, messages.INFO,
                'Incorrect data'
            )
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: Так Вы закомментировали код Comment.objects.create(**self.form.cleaned_data) - он как раз и создает комментарий из данных формы.

Answer (score 1):

Скиньте код формы и модели для более точного решения проблемы.

В качестве решения и удобства советую использовать [формы моделей](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__' # или ['field1', 'field2', ..., 'fieldN']

    author = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        required=False,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.author = kwargs.pop('author', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean():
        cd = super().clean()

        if self.author and not self.author.is_anonymous() and self.author.is_authenticated():
            cs['author'] = self.author
        return cd



...
# view
...
    ...
        ....
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, author=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            ....
       ....
```